# ProgressBar gets cut off

Tags: android, xml

So, I am trying to wrap around a **circular ProgressBar around a TextView**. Whenever I do this, it gets cut-off (how much depends on device), and there is also a ridiculous padding between the left side of the screen and the `ProgressBar`.
This is how I want it to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPIaM.jpg

The image is actually from the android studio preview (dont know why it works there)

However for some reasons it looks like this (Samsung S8):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyKYe.jpg

On the OnePlus One its even more on the right and even more cut off.
With `android:layout_marginleft="-xxdp"` I can move the cut off part from the progress bar, to the left where I want it to, but since the margin depends quite hard on the device, I would prefer to use an alternative way (and this also doesnt restore the full progressbar).

And here the complete xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@color/blue_top_bar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/barTimer"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:max="500"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:progress="500"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress_bar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/countdown_gameplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/chicken_yellow" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

just found out it has something to do with this java code:

```
Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f, 250f, 273f);
        an.setFillAfter(true);
        barTimer.startAnimation(an);
```

It seems like the rotateAnimation is the reason for the problem. Anyone an idea how to change this, so it still rotates the bar 90° degress, without cutting off and adding a random padding?

Appreciate any help
ty

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `RealtiveLayout` of your `XML` file:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5 s"
    android:id="@+id/txt_secondsleft"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/progressBar1"
    />
```

Hope it serves your purpose....